# What is the make and model of this 16" kids bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike

I've seen this picture in one of the Facebook groups and was curious to what the brand is and model. I found a lot of close makes but not the actual bicycle on internet and gave up after searching for hours.

[image]

Comment: Does it really matter, for a kids' bike? Is there that much difference between different models?

Comment: By the way, you mean 16". 16' is sixteen feet. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would call that a generic low end kids bike.

The manufacturer will be some anonymous factory in asia, making the same frame for a dozen different contracts.  The only variation will be in paint and perhaps decals.

Any "model" specification will be created by the assembler/importer/distributor and won't really tell you much.  It is probably as simple as "the boy's 16 inch wheel model" and that differs from the girl's one by paint colour, basket, and perhaps streamers or maybe crashpads on the top tube or handlebars.

---

What I do see is a bike with one brake, a rear caliper brake only.  This bike may have a coaster brake in the rear wheel because I can see what looks like a reaction arm under the left chainstay, but its very strange to have a caliper brake on the same wheel as a coaster brake.  There is clearly no front brake because there is no second brake lever.

The cranks appear to be a one-piece unit, which is a hallmark of a lower-end bike.  Higher bikes have three-piece cranksets where the bottom-bracket axle is a separate piece to the two crank arms (you might know them as "pedal arms")

The frame shows "value engineering" where the design has less metal in it by using a shorter top tube.  This also makes it easier to weld at the head tube - Shorter weld runs means less heat so less distortion.

---

Frankly - look at the kid.  He's having an awesome time rocking out on the bike.  He'd have as much fun on any working bike, as long as its safe and functional, and he has somewhere to ride it.

Comment: was just curious! thanks. can be closed if want to.